# Paralelizar un bucle

Tags: c

Necesito paralelizar el primer bucle `for`, utilizando OpenMP. He estado haciendo varias pruebas y no consigo resolver las dependencias. ¿Sugerencias? Este es el código:

```
int process_data( int n, Planet p[], Point3D *pcm )
{
    int i, j, ngbi, k, max;
    double dx, dy, dz,d, m;
    Point3D cm; // center of mass
    cm.x = cm.y = cm.z = 0; m = 0;
    //ejercicio 1 , calculamos el tiempo antes del for
    double t1, t2;
    t1=omp_get_wtime();
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        // Accumulate mass and weighted position to compute the center of mass
        m += p[i].m;
        cm.x += p[i].m*p[i].p.x;
        cm.y += p[i].m*p[i].p.y;
        cm.z += p[i].m*p[i].p.z;

        // Update count of neighboring planets 
        ngbi = 0;
        for (j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
            // Compute distance between planet i and planet j
            dx = p[i].p.x - p[j].p.x;
            dy = p[i].p.y - p[j].p.y;
            dz = p[i].p.z - p[j].p.z;
            d = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
            if ( d < NGB_DST ) {
                // Planets i and j are neighbors. Update number of neighbors
                // for both planets
                ngbi++;
                p[j].ngb++;
            }
        }
        p[i].ngb += ngbi;
    }
    // Finish computation of the center of mass
    if ( m > EPS ) {
        cm.x /= m; cm.y /= m; cm.z /= m;
    }
    
    // Find the planet with most neighbors
    k = 0; max = -1;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if ( p[i].ngb > max ) {
            max = p[i].ngb; k = i;
        }
    }
    //ejercicio 1, calculamos el tiempo después del for y lo restamos al t1
    t2=omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Calculation time: %f\n", t2-t1);
    *pcm = cm;
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Publica el código como texto; como imagen no se puede copiar y pegar en la IDE.

Comment: son demasiados caracteres

Comment: ya está actualizado

Comment: En serio no eres capaz de presentar un ejemplo más pequeño? un caso práctico que se centre en el bucle y deje de lado todo lo innecesario

Comment: perdona, es la primera pregunta que formulo aquí, creo que así tiene más sentido

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con paralelizar un bucle?

Comment: con openmp, puedes mejorar el tiempo de cálculo de una función, consiguiendo que se realicen n hilos al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Y con paralelizar me refiero a conseguir que se obtenga el mismo resultado, en un tiempo inferior.